# How to fix a view from going off of a page when it is constrained to a card view

Tags: java, android, android-cardview, android-constraintlayout

I have recently converted over an android project into androidx and I am having issues with trying to stop views going off of the page. My layout is as follows, a Constraint Layout that contains a Card View and a Text View. Within this Card View I have a Constraint Layout that contains the Text View. Outside of the Card View I have a Button which is constrained to the Card View.

The issue with this is that when I run the program the Card View goes off of the screen and the button moves all the way to the top even though they are all constrained properly.

I will show below the code I am using to achieve this and an image of my result on the emulator.

Here is the layout in the editor [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6coHr.jpg

Here is the layout shown on the Emulator [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ahkl.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/materialButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="Text View Test"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/materialButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="256dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your layout is getting pushed because of this line:**

```
android:layout_marginBottom="256dp"
```

Different phones got different screen size, in your layout you are using fixed size on your view ("256dp") and it makes your layout non-responsive.

So what may look good on your preview may not look the same on a real phone.

If you want to place some view anywhere on your screen and keep it responsive I recommend using [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html), something like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/materialButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Text View Test"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/materialButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline13"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And it will look like this:**

[image]

Comment: Hi! This solved it for me, it also opened my eyes to using guidelines which I haven't come across before. It also led me to looking into barriers as well. Using guidelines has made me go through more parts of my project and add them. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not so sure about android x but the constraint layouts are used for removing the nested layouts so, you should not be using constraint layout inside card view. Try this code as a reference. It might help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="Text View Test"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/materialButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cv_text" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

please remove this line from button attribute :

```
   android:layout_marginBottom="256dp"
```

your are just pushing to button to the top by setting the `margin_bottom` , and why it's shown on the preview and not on the device just because of the different screen size